# How could you use constant data to conditionally display meteor sections?

Tags: meteor

I'm intrigued by this snippet in the meteor documentation:

```
Helpers can also be used to pass in constant data.
// Works fine with {{#each sections}}
Template.report.sections = ["Situation", "Complication", "Resolution"];
```

This makes me think that you may be able to pass in a list of the templates you wish to display at any point in time:

```
{{#each sections}}
<div>{{> this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

but this throws the error:

```
Template names shouldn't contain '.' or '/' (compiling client/cjblog.html)
```

Can anyone explain how you could use constant data to conditionally display sections?

Comment: You're missing one "}". Do you think this may be reason you're getting this error?

Comment: No, that was a sloppy copy from the code, but thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass static data like you've shown and display it:

```
{{#each sections}} {{this}} {{/each}}
```

However, you cannot that simply create a dynamic template – the line

```
{{> this}}
```

will not work. There are several workarounds for this, probably the most flexible one is to create a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('renderThing', function(thing) {
  if (Template[thing])
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[thing]());
});
```

Then you could use it like that:

```
{{#each sections}}
    {{renderThing this}}
{{/each}}
```